# Select Top 2 Comma Delimited w/SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select the top 2 records and put them in one column separated by a comma.

Here is what I have so far, but I can't get it to work.

```
UPDATE #Temp 
SET TopTwoInactiveDDSRenewalFeeID = ( STUFF (
SELECT TOP 2 ',' + I.InvoiceID 
FROM DB..rInvoice I
WHERE I.rUltimateEntityID = entID
AND I.ObjectID = 18
AND I.ObjectTypeIDRAW = 1741
AND I.rParentObjectID = 2
AND I.rParentPK = LicID
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')

)
```

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.*

I am using this post as reference, but it's not working for me: [display the top 3 records in a comma separated in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368204/display-the-top-3-records-in-a-comma-separated-in-one-column)

Not sure how to write this one.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Are you getting an error? Do you have sample data and expected output?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work like this:

`UPDATE #Temp 
SET TopTwoInactiveDDSRenewalFeeID = ( SELECT STUFF ((

 SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 ',' + CONVERT(varchar, I.InvoiceID )
 FROM DB..rInvoice I
 WHERE I.rUltimateEntityID = entID
 AND I.ObjectID = 18
 AND I.ObjectTypeIDRAW = 1741
 AND I.rParentObjectID = 2
 AND I.rParentPK = LicID
 ORDER BY',' + CONVERT(varchar,I.InvoiceID)
 FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

)
FROM #Temp
`

Answer (score 1):

I would try to change the following line. Having the space after the comma is necessary for the STUFF to work properly. It would be better if you could load test data into sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/.

```
SELECT TOP 2 ',' + I.InvoiceID
```

to

```
SELECT TOP 2 ', ' + I.InvoiceID
```

Here's another example for you,

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Values') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #Values
END

IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #Temp
END

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
ID                  INT
,CommaDelimited     VARCHAR(500)
)
INSERT INTO #Temp
(
ID
)
SELECT 1

CREATE TABLE #Values
(
Value               CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #Values
(
Value
)
SELECT '1'
UNION ALL SELECT '2'
UNION ALL SELECT '3'
UNION ALL SELECT '4'


UPDATE #Temp 
SET CommaDelimited = STUFF((SELECT TOP 2 ', '+Value FROM #Values FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```